# How do I use heat.exe with Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, heat

The Wix toolset (v.3) has a tool called *heat.exe* for "harvesting" files in a particular location and generating a *.wxs* file which specifies the files which will be part of an installer package.

Our current Wix code uses heat to harvest our application files, but now I am trying to set this up in a Visual Studio project for the installer, which uses the Wix v3 Visual Studio 2022 extension.

How do I get heat working in in conjunction with a Visual Studio project?  Does that even make sense?

Or should I simply run heat once, manually, and then include the generated *.wxs* in the project as a source file?